# Corrupted Recycle Bin?

Tags: windows, windows-10, recycle-bin

I used a freeware duplicate removal tool called "dupeGuru" to remove some duplicates. It does not have an option to just delete the files, only an option to "move selected files to recycle bin." The first few times went fine, but then I selected a group of files that was larger than the max size of the recycle bin, about 300 Gigs of files. Now whenever I right click the recycle bin Windows File Explorer crashes. Anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the size allocated to the Recycle Bin?  You can also try to configure your system, so deleted items are permanently deleted, that should clear it also.

Comment: Have you reported the bug to dupeGuru?  Seems like it's a trivial check for the software developers to avoid the maximum size of the Recycling Bin.

Answer (score 0):

#### It does not have an option to just delete the files

Actually it does. When you click "Actions" > "Send Marked to Recycle Bin" the following dialog is displayed:

[image]

Selecting "Directly delete files" and clicking "Proceed" will delete the files directly, bypassing the Recycle Bin.